# Convert numeric struct to textual line of numbers on C++

Tags: c++, json, struct

Need some idea how to convert struct (might be also nested) to line of strings where each string is the number of the struct according to the order.
I hope i clear enough.
For example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int a;
  float b;
};
struct External
{
 double c;
 MyStruct d;
};

void main()
{
 External x;
 
 x.c = 2.345;
 x.d.a = 12;
 x.d.b = 3.8f;

 std:string res = convert_to_string (&x);
 cout << res;
 // Expected print result:
 // "2.345, 12, 3.8"
}
```

The struct can be very long, so the solution of sorts of itoa(dtoa) or sprintf for each field is possible, but very long and needs code update for every struct change.
Probably some kind of struct run-time or precompile parsing and serialization is needed here.

Ideas ?

Comment: define a `ostream & operator <<(ostream &, T)` for each struct

Comment: @alex If code was `x.d.b = 3.799999952f;`, would you expect output of 3.8 or 3.799999952?  To print all `float` distinctively, 9 significant decimal places are often used.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, it doesn't really matter. Let's take for simplicity the number as is.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? C++ to the rescue :)

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  float b;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyStruct& ms) {
    std::cout << std::to_string(ms.a) << " " << std::to_string(ms.b);
    return os;
  }
};

struct External {
 double c;
 MyStruct d;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const External& e) {
    std::cout << std::to_string(e.c) << " " << e.d;
    return os;
  }
};

int main() {
 External x;
 
 x.c = 2.345;
 x.d.a = 12;
 x.d.b = 3.8f;

 std::cout << x << std::endl;
 // Expected print result:
 // "2.345, 12, 3.8"
}
```

Or if you really want a string:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  float b;
  std::string to_string() const {
    std::string str = std::to_string(this->a);
    str += " ";
    str += std::to_string(this->b);
    return str;
  }
};

struct External {
  double c;
  MyStruct d;
  std::string to_string() const {
    std::string str = std::to_string(this->c);
    str += " ";
    str += this->d.to_string();
    return str;
  }
};

int main() {
 External x;
 
 x.c = 2.345;
 x.d.a = 12;
 x.d.b = 3.8f;

 std::cout << x.to_string() << std::endl;
 // Expected print result:
 // "2.345, 12, 3.8"
}
```

Comment: your `operator<<` writes to `std::cout` no matter what stream was passed

Comment: This is possible solution, but i prefer do not change the existing structs, as they are coming from third party source in separate header.

Comment: Then I suppose you would have to write a function that takes an ```External``` as parameter and prints the struct / puts it in a string. I don't really see any other way. If each member would be of the same time, e.g. ```int```, then you could take an ```int*``` and print the struct without knowing the actual structure. But that is not the case here.
@463035818_is_not_a_number I know, that is because in the example it was only printed with cout. But that is why the string version is there. Anyways, thanks for the notice.

Comment: @MarcellJuhász, yes, this is the straight forward and long way. I thought about something that parse the structs and stores the offsets and types of the numbers in some array, and then build the string taking the offsets as numbers. So what I'm missing is actually the parsing function.